# What's the best way to add records to managed objects?

Tags: ios, json, core-data

I want to use a JSON file to send app data updates. The data are managed objects.

However:

1. I don't want to overwrite existing data (that will likely include user generated records and modifications), and
2. I want this operation to be as swift as possible (no pun.. I'm still in Obj-C).

Can someone point me in the right direction here..

This is how I'm starting the app now:

```
NSError* err = nil;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Words" ofType:@"json"];
    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                              options:kNilOptions
                                                error:&err];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    [jsonArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        WordEntity *word = [NSEntityDescription
                            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"WordEntity"
                            inManagedObjectContext:context];

        word.greekText = [obj objectForKey:@"greektext"];
        word.englishText = [obj objectForKey:@"englishtext"];
      word.uid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [obj objectForKey:@"uid"]];
        word.category = [obj valueForKey:@"category"];


        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}
```

Thanks for any help..

Comment: You init `jsonArray` once, and then reinit it 2 lines later? What? Why are you using `valueForKey:` when setting `word.category`? Using two `NSError`s?

Comment: Late night errors. Thanks for pointing them out

Comment: I believe this post points me in the right direction: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/06/02/saving-json-to-core-data/